# Set command line options with slashes for debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, command-line

I have two CLI switches in my application: `/s` and `/l`. I've set those in VCExpress 2010 at Properties/Debugging as `/sSomething /lotherSomething`, but my program is still executed as if nothing was specified.
If I run it through CMD with the same switches, I get a crash (hence the debugging need).

Comment: Hmmm what program?  Without showing us your code, your best bet is to save a minidump when you crash, then load it into Visual Studio.  Perhaps your program is not parsing the command line arguments correctly, and that is giving you undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm basically using a third-party library that loads my program. I know it isn't being loaded because when I run it through visual studio I don't get the crash with the same arguments.

Comment: the /s switch basically tells the library that My program specifically is being loaded, so if it doesn't get passed to visual studio nothing happens.

Comment: Did you put those parameters under command arguments?  If you set a breakpoint on the first statement after main, what to argc and argv say?

Comment: main is on the third party lib. I'm not hitting any breakpoint on my own module. My command line args are `/sScript /lLog`.

Comment: (had the parameters been passed correctly, I should've gotten at least a proper crash instead of a default return from the main library)